# My mic is not working on Skype (iOS)

Tags: audio, skype, microphone, ios

This morning I update my iPad 2 to iOS 7 and when I went to do a call on Skype, they are not hearing me. Is there something wrong with the settings or is it something else?

Comment: Check your settings, you now need to provide permission for an app to use your microphone. Settings > Privacy > Microphone.  You may need to reinstall Skype to force it to make the request. Guesswork, btw, hence not an answer.

Comment: Does your microphone shows up in Skype settings?

Answer (score 3):

If you accidentially disallowed Skype app accessing your microphone on iOS7 you can change the setting via: `Settings -> Privacy -> Microphone -> Skype`

Answer (score 2):

Ensure `Settings > Privacy > Microphone > Skype` is turned on.

Comment: Next time, if you use bit more words to make your answer, we would reward you :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem.  It is not only on Skype, any app requiring microphone access, even if granted, does not work on my iPad 2 after installing iOS 7.  Uninstalling Skype did not help either.

You might want to check other apps that use Microphone input to make sure it's not just a Skype issue. It could be hardware failure or an OS issue.